# how to continue playing second song after first song is finished playing in AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, avplayer

How can I start next song immediately with AVPlayer? I have collections of song selected from iPod Library in MPMediaItemCollection which is shown in my UITableView **[myPlaylistTable]** . i know i have to use NSNotification to check whether song has finished ,but i dont know how to play the second or next song as soon as the current song finish playing .I have posted my code below

If anyone can help me with the solution it would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
   in viewDidLoad i have initialized 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self.myPlaylistTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.myPlaylistTable indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];

    UInt32 doSetProperty = 0;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (
                             kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
                             sizeof (doSetProperty),
                             &doSetProperty
                             );

    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    myPlaylistTable.hidden=YES;

    playlistSongsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(nextSongPlaying:)
                                                     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                   object:[myPlayer currentItem]];

}      



-(void) mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {

    // Dismiss selection view
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    // Get AVAsset
    NSURL* assetUrl = [mediaItemCollection.representativeItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetUrl options:nil];


    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];


    myPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    [playlistSongsArray addObjectsFromArray:mediaItemCollection.items];

    NSLog(@" Playlist songs  %@",playlistSongsArray);

    [self.myPlaylistTable reloadData];

    [myPlayer play];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder 
{
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: kCellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];


            UILabel *playbackDurationLabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(205, 88, 103, 18)];
            playbackDurationLabel.tag = 100;
            playbackDurationLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            playbackDurationLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

            playbackDurationLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:playbackDurationLabel];

    }   

    if (tableView == myPlaylistTable)
    {
        MPMediaItem *mediaItem = (MPMediaItem *)[playlistSongsArray objectAtIndex:row]; 
        MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];


        if (mediaItem) 
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
            cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;

            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
            cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines=0;

            UILabel *songDurationLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
            songDurationLabel.text=[self secondsFormatted:[[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] intValue]];

            NSLog(@"song duration - %@",[[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] stringValue]);

            if (artwork != nil) 
            {
                cell.imageView.image = [artwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
            }
            else
            {
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noArtworkImage.png"];
            }
        }   

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated: YES];
    }

    return cell;
}



    -(void)nextSongPlaying:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
         //What stuff to do 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

DShah i did it this way ..can u check if it is correct  in my viewDidLoad ..

```
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(nextSongPlaying:) 
name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification 
object:[myPlayer currentItem]];

- (void)nextSongPlaying:(NSNotification *)notification 
{ 

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [notification object];
[playerItem seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[myPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Is this working?? If not then you need to change the current Item to next Item in List. Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661859/my-player-stops-after-playing-first-song

Comment: Just for your Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716259/iphone-avplayer-streaming-from-remote-url-in-phonegap  and also look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605905/mixed-video-type-content-queued-in-an-avqueueplayer-on-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Apple's Link for help : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html

This link explain about **Playing Multiple Items**. You can use `AVQueuePlayer` which is subclass of `AVPlayer` for queuing the multiple songs.

**EDIT**

Please see the GitHub link : https://github.com/crocodella/AVPlayerSample
For explanation : http://www.crocodella.com.br/2011/01/using-avplayer-to-play-background-music-from-library/

This link has same thing that you want.

Comment: NSArray *items = <#An array of player items#>;
AVQueuePlayer *queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:items];

AVPlayerItem *anItem = <#Get a player item#>;
if ([queuePlayer canInsertItem:anItem afterItem:nil]) {
    [queuePlayer insertItem:anItem afterItem:nil];
}

Since i am fetching songs from ipod library and putting it on custom tableview how it will know that song is finished and the next song has to continue

Comment: Since you have registered the notification for AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, whenever song will get finished your selector method will get fired...

Comment: yeah i dont know how to fetch the next song and start playing after current song finishes playing

Comment: Same way as you started the first song, but the only difference is now you will write the logic inside the selector method. Handle the Selector method whenever the first song finish.

Comment: Refer to section **Responding to a Change in Status** in link, a KVO is registered. It is similar to Notification (remember but not same as notification).

Comment: its working in background i just want to the player to continue playing the next song as soon as the song which is playing finishes

Comment: Can you include some code how you are doing? so that i can help you with your logic. Please include your selector method code.

Comment: could u just do the continuation to next song and from first song problem and when i try to add new songs the old song which was playing will stop and new song which was playing starts playing, that would be a big help .. i'll figure out the rest of the problem .. cause i need to submit this project to my prof in 2 days :(

Comment: @orgami: Here is the exact solution what you are asking for Second song to start login : http://stevetranby.com/blog/2010/09/background-music-queue-with-avplayer-and-ios4/